# the onDrop function is not working ins react-dnd

Tags: javascript, reactjs, drag-and-drop, draggable, react-dnd

I am using react dnd and the onDrop function is not working I tried adding console log to confirm the console log is also not been triggered.

I tried multiple ways according to online resources but nothing worked. this is my code.

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import { DndProvider, useDrag, useDrop } from 'react-dnd';
import { HTML5Backend } from 'react-dnd-html5-backend';
import { Modal, Row, Col, Button } from 'antd';
import './style.scss';
import Icons from './constants'

const ItemType = 'IMAGE';

const ImagePopup = ({ image, visible, onClose }) => {
  return (
    <Modal
      title="Image Dropped"
      open={visible}
      onOk={onClose}
      onCancel={onClose}
    >
      <img src={image} alt="Dropped" style={{ maxWidth: '100%' }} />
    </Modal>
  );
};

const DraggableImage = ({ image }) => {
  const [, ref] = useDrag({
    type: ItemType,
    item: { image },
  });

  return (
    <Col span={4}>
        <div ref={ref} className="draggable-image">
            <img src={image} alt="Draggable" style={{ maxWidth: '100%' }} />
        </div>
    </Col>
  );
};

const ImageGrid = () => {
  const [droppedImages, setDroppedImages] = useState([]);
  const [popupVisible, setPopupVisible] = useState(false);
  const [popupImage, setPopupImage] = useState('');

  const handleDrop = (index, item) => {
    console.log('hi')

    console.log(index)
    console.log(item)

    const newDroppedImages = [...droppedImages];
    newDroppedImages[index] = item.image;
    setDroppedImages(newDroppedImages);
    setPopupImage(item.image);
    setPopupVisible(true);
  };

    const renderGrid = () => {
        const grid = [];
      
        for (let row = 0; row < 4; row++) {
          const rowItems = [];
          for (let col = 0; col < 6; col++) {
            const index = row * 6 + col;
            const droppedImage = droppedImages[index];
      
            rowItems.push(
              <Col key={index} span={4}>
                <div className='drop-box-style'>
                    <div
                        className="drop-box"
                        onDrop={(e) => {
                            e.preventDefault();
                            const item = JSON.parse(e.dataTransfer.getData(ItemType));
                            handleDrop(index, item);
                        }}
                        onDragOver={(e) => e.preventDefault()}
                        draggable="true" 
                    >
                    {droppedImage && (
                        <Image src={droppedImage} alt="Dropped" preview={false} />
                    )}
                    </div>
                </div>
              </Col>
            );
          }
          grid.push(rowItems);
        }
      
        return grid.map((row, rowIndex) => (
          <Row key={rowIndex} gutter={[16, 16]}>
            {row}
          </Row>
        ));
    };

    const draggedItem = { image: '' };

    return (
        <DndProvider backend={HTML5Backend}>
            <div className="drapable-wrapper">
                <div className="top-images">
                    <Row>
                        {[Icons.OneSeat, Icons.TwoSeat, Icons.FourSeat, Icons.SixSeat, Icons.EightSeat, Icons.TenSeat].map((image, index) => (
                            <DraggableImage key={index} image={image} />
                        ))}
                    </Row>
                </div>
                <div className="grid-container">
                    {renderGrid()}
                </div>
                <ImagePopup
                    image={popupImage}
                    visible={popupVisible}
                    onClose={() => setPopupVisible(false)}
                />
            </div>
        </DndProvider>
    );
};

export default ImageGrid;
```

The purpose of this code is in the top there would be 6 images and in the bottom there will be a 6*4 grid with boxes The images should be able to drag and drop in to the boxes in the grid.

react version 17 and the react dnd version 14